# Can Guice MapBinding Returns Distinct Instance

Tags: java, guice

I have a Gucie Binding setup like this:

```
    MapBinder<String, MyInterface> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, MyInterface.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding("a").to(MyClassA.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding("b").to(MyClassB.class);
```

MyClassA implements MyInterface of course.

Everytime I get query the injected map with a key, it always returns me the same instance:

```
class UserClass {
    private final Map<String, MyInterface> map;
    public UserClass(Map<String, MyInterface> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void MyMethod() {
        MyInterface instance1 = map.get("a");
        MyInterface instance2 = map.get("a");
        .....
    }

     ......
}
```

Here instance1 and instance2 I got are always the same object. Is there any way to configure Gucie to always returns different instances from MapBinder?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by injecting `Map<String, Provider<MyInterface>>` instead of `Map<String, MyInterface>`.

```
interface MyInterface {}

class MyClassA implements MyInterface {}
class MyClassB implements MyInterface {}

class UserClass {
    @Inject private Map<String, Provider<MyInterface>> map;

    public void MyMethod() {
        Provider<MyInterface> instance1 = map.get("a");
        Provider<MyInterface> instance2 = map.get("a");
    }
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            MapBinder<String, MyInterface> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, MyInterface.class);
            mapBinder.addBinding("a").to(MyClassA.class);
            mapBinder.addBinding("b").to(MyClassB.class);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Does that mean I have to map my key to Providers: mapBinder.addBinding("b").toProvider(MyClassBProvider.class); Does it also mean I have to create a provider for every key I have?

Comment: Doc link: [MapBinder docs](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) (which lists `Provider<V>` injection as well).